# Manjaro update-grub syntax error

Tags: kernel, grub, manjaro

After letting my computer sit for an extended time without updating, I ran Pacman -Syu for a full system update. During the update the process was interrupted or something because the grub entries were not automatically updated with the new 5.2 kernel entries, leaving an unresponsive 4.2 entry and a working legacy kernel. I bolted into the legacy kernel, updated the mirrors, made sure that the kernels were installed and then tried to run update-grub. This returned a syntax error and the process failed. Does anyone have a fix for this?

```
ecgoss@ecgossmanjaro ~]$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for ecgoss: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.3-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.3-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.2-rt-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.2-rt-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.2-rt-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.3-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.3-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.2-rt-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.2-rt-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.2-rt-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64-fallback.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda3@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda3@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.3-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.3-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.2-rt-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.2-rt-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.2-rt-x86_64-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/amd-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-4.19-x86_64-fallback.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda3@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 450
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

Comment: Please post the full results of `update-grub` (add to your qeustion).

Comment: Was the original grub configuration edited in any way (`grub-customizer` or manually)?

Comment: I will add to the question when I'm home. The grub configuration was not edited in any way. It was just stock

Comment: I have updated the post with the full results from update grub

Comment: It looks like the syntax error is in one of the scripts under `/etc/grub.d/`. Check them file by file.

Comment: @Hermann what would I exactly be looking for?

Comment: @EthanGoss You can either disable (remove executable bit) all scripts and then re-enable them one by one, while running `update-grub` each time until the error occurs. It is either in or one of the files after `20_memtest86+`, sorted lexicographically. You can also run `env pkgdatadir=/usr/lib/grub bash -x /etc/grub.d/40_custom` to see where bash finds the syntax error exactly.